# How can I use a searchBar in a TableView with multiple sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

This is my case: I have a table view in a navigator with 4 sections, and each section has some number of cells. I would like to use a search bar to see the content of my table view, but I haven't been able to do so as I would like it and the tutorials I've followed only describe 1 table view with 1 section and an "n" number of rows, but nothing about a table view with n sections and m rows per section. And the ones that I have found don't have an answer yet. So I would like to ask you guys for some help to know how to implement a search bar under the conditions that I mentioned before, please.

As I introduced before, I have a table view with 4 sections and some cells in each section, when I click on one cell, it takes me to another view controller that has a textView showing the data for that section and row. I would like to implement a search bar so that the user does not have to scroll down throughout the whole table view to find what s/he needs, but so far I haven't found a tutorial/example using a search bar with sections, they use a single tableview with one section and many cells. I already tried to implement SearchBarDelegate (using the tutorials that I've found) but it does not work as I expected. 
So here I come to you to see if you can share some of your knowledge and wisdom to help me out with this, please.

This is the code for my tableViewController (the code between /* */ is the code without implementing the searchBar, so it would only shows the table view with its sections and cells):

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
// MARK: - Variables and Constants
var selectedIndex = Int()
var selectedSection = Int()
var textKind = [
    ["""
    SECTION 1, ROW 0 \n
    Esto debe venir de section 1 row 0, y para hacerlo realmente largo es necesario meter un montón de cosas irrelevantes para ver si respeta los espacios y los renglones del textView. Gracias de nada.
    """,
     """
    SECTION 1, ROW 1 \n
    Esto debe venir de section 1 row 1. Una vez más es necesario asegurarse de que los márgenes y formatos de texto son respetados. De otro modo habrá que corregirlos. \n
    Aquí hay un salto de línea. A ver qué tal sale.
    """,

    """
    SECTION 1, ROW 2 \n
    Esto debe venir de section 1 row 2. \n \n

    OTRO SUBTÍTULO DENTRO DE LA SECCIÓN. \n
    Se usarán 2 nuevas líneas cuando haya que añadir algún título o subtítulo dentro del textView. Por cuestiones de estética visual.
    """,

    """
    SECTION 1, ROW 3 \n
    Esto debe venir de section 1 row 3
    """],

    ["""
    SECTION 2 ROW 0 \n
    Esto debe venir de section 2 row 0. Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda. \n \n \n \n \n \n

        Aquí sigue la onda pedorra.
    """,
     "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 1",
     "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 2",
     "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 3",
     "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 4",
     "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 5",
     "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 6"],

    ["Esto debe venir de section 3 row 0",
     "Esto debe venir de section 3 row 1",
     "Esto debe venir de section 3 row 2"],

    ["Esto debe venir de section 4 row 0",
     "Esto debe venir de section 4 row 1",
     "Esto debe venir de section 4 row 2",
     "Esto debe venir de section 4 row 3",
     "Esto debe venir de section 4 row 4",
     "Esto debe venir de section 4 row 5",
     "Esto debe venir de section 4 row 6",
     "Esto debe venir de section 4 row 7"]
]

var sectionsNames:[String] = ["section 1", "section 2", "section 3" , "section 4"]
var section1Content:[String] = ["uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"]
var section2Content:[String] = ["a", "be", "ce", "de", "e", "efe", "ge"]
var section3Content:[String] = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]
var section4Content:[String] = ["ichi", "ni", "san", "shi", "go", "roku", "nana", "hachi"]
@IBOutlet weak var searchBarVariable: UISearchBar!
var searching = false
var searchingData = [String]()

// MARK: - viewDidLoad()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBarVariable.delegate = self
}

// MARK: - TableView configuration (sections, cellForRowAt, etc.).
// MARK: - Number of sections
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionsNames.count
}

// MARK: - Sections' titles
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sectionsNames[section]
}

// MARK: - Number of rows per section
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if searching {
        return searchingData.count
    } else {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return section1Content.count

        case 1:
            return section2Content.count

        case 2:
            return section3Content.count

        case 3:
            return section4Content.count

        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

   /* switch section {
    case 0:
    return section1Content.count

    case 1:
        return section2Content.count

    case 2:
        return section3Content.count

    case 3:
        return section4Content.count

    default:
        return 0
    } */
}

// MARK: - Cells' content
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sourceCell", for: indexPath)

    if searching {
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchingData[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel!.text = section1Content[indexPath.row]

        case 1:
            cell.textLabel!.text = section2Content[indexPath.row]

        case 2:
            cell.textLabel!.text = section3Content[indexPath.row]

        case 3:
            cell.textLabel!.text = section4Content[indexPath.row]
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    /*switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel!.text = section1Content[indexPath.row]

    case 1:
        cell.textLabel!.text = section2Content[indexPath.row]

    case 2:
        cell.textLabel!.text = section3Content[indexPath.row]

    case 3:
        cell.textLabel!.text = section4Content[indexPath.row]
    default:
        break
    } */

    return cell
}

// MARK: - DidSelectRowAt
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedSection = indexPath.section
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToInfo", sender: self)
}

// MARK: - prepare(for segue:...)
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToInfo" {
        let vc: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        vc.viewTextText = textKind[self.selectedSection][self.selectedIndex]
        print(vc.viewTextText)
    }
}
}

// MARK: - Searchbar in tableview
extension TableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchingData = section1Content.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()}) + section2Content.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()}) + section3Content.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()}) + section4Content.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
    searching = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

This is the code of the viewController linked to the previous tableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Variables and Constants
var viewTextText:String = ""

// MARK: - ViewController components
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewTextViewText: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

// MARK: - viewDidLoad()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    arrangingTextView()
}

func arrangingTextView() {
    self.viewTextViewText.text = viewTextText
    self.viewTextViewText.font = UIFont(name: "helvetica", size: 24.0)
    self.viewTextViewText.textAlignment = .justified
}
}
```

What it is expected: when typing in the search bar, it must be shown only the section(s) and cells with the matching typing in the search bar. When I click on the wished information, it should take me to the viewController containing the information of that section and cell.

What it really happens: when typing in the search bar, it shows the same content on the 4 sections and their content. When I click on the row, it takes me to unrelated and false information to that cell.

If you reproduce my code you will observe better what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is not appropriate. Instead of using a flag variable as `searching` and handling different scenarios, all you need to do is to define only a single array for the entire procedure. In your case your data source array would look like this:

```
[["uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"],["a", "be", "ce", "de", "e", "efe", "ge"],["alpha", "beta", "gamma"],["ichi", "ni", "san", "shi", "go", "roku", "nana", "hachi"]]
```

Now, everything is much more easier to handle and implement. For example the switch case in number of rows delegate function will be replaced by:

```
return dataSource[section].count
```

What you want to do here is to map two distinct arrays to each other when a search result is tapped. I suggest you to create a class when you have multiple attributes relating to one thing:

```
struct Item {
var title : String // this is cell's title
var text : String // this is what will be shown on the next view controller when a cell is tapped.
}
```

Your data source will then look like this:

```
var dataSource : [[Item]] = [[Item(title: "uno" , text: """
SECTION 1, ROW 0 \n
Esto debe venir de section 1 row 0, y para hacerlo realmente largo es necesario meter un montón de cosas irrelevantes para ver si respeta los espacios y los renglones del textView. Gracias de nada.
""") , Item(title: "dos" , text: """
SECTION 1, ROW 1 \n
Esto debe venir de section 1 row 1. Una vez más es necesario asegurarse de que los márgenes y formatos de texto son respetados. De otro modo habrá que corregirlos. \n
Aquí hay un salto de línea. A ver qué tal sale.
""" ) , Item(title: "tres" , text: """
SECTION 1, ROW 2 \n
Esto debe venir de section 1 row 2. \n \n

OTRO SUBTÍTULO DENTRO DE LA SECCIÓN. \n
Se usarán 2 nuevas líneas cuando haya que añadir algún título o subtítulo dentro del textView. Por cuestiones de estética visual.
""" ), Item(title: "cuatro" , text: """
SECTION 1, ROW 3 \n
Esto debe venir de section 1 row 3
""" )] , [Item(title: "a" , text: """
SECTION 2 ROW 0 \n
Esto debe venir de section 2 row 0. Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda. \n \n \n \n \n \n

Aquí sigue la onda pedorra.
""" ) , Item(title: "be" , text: "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 1" ) , Item(title: "ce" , text: "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 2" ) , Item(title: "de" , text: "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 3" ) , Item(title: "e" , text: "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 4" ) , Item(title: "efe" , text: "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 1" ) , Item(title: "ge" , text: "Esto debe venir de section 2 row 5" )]]
```

Now in your search delegate functions you need to remove unwanted result from the data source array based on the text or simply reset the array to defaults when cancel button is tapped. Once you've done that, all you need to do is to just reload table view:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    self.dataSource = values
    var filteredDataSource : [[Item]] = []
    for items in dataSource {
        let filteredItems = items.filter { (item) -> Bool in
            if item.title.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased() {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        filteredDataSource.append(filteredItems)
    }
    self.dataSource = filteredDataSource
    tableView.reloadData()

}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.dataSource = values //reseting data source to defaults
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And when you select a row, you pass the section and row number incorrectly in your code. In order to pass corresponding data to the next view controller appropriately, you need to do this in your prepare for segue function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    //assuming your next view controller class's name is ViewController.
    guard let detailViewController = segue.destination as? ViewController,
        let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row,
        let section = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.section
        else {
            return
    }
    detailViewController.item = dataSource[section][row] //passing selected item object.
}
```

Finally, in your next view controller you have the item object which has both title and text properties. In your case you want to display its text property.
Hope this helps you!

**EDIT**

Complete solution on [github](https://github.com/faderani/Searching-Table-View).

Comment: Hello Soroush, thanks for your reply. I was able to reproduce up to `return dataSource[section].count`, but then I got lost with the rest of your explanation. So var I was able to reproduce what I had done (sections with their content and showing the information corresponding to the cell clicked) using your suggestion.
Could you please (if that's ok with you) to share the code of the search delegate functions and the part of  defining an id for my items to make them traceable to the next view controller?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I edited my answer with full implementation. @J_A_F_Casillas

Comment: Thanks Soroush, I checked it already and unfortunately your procedure is not the correct one. If you combine my code with your approach and test it you will see what I mean. I must show the info inside the textKind array and your code shows the cell's content and that's not the objective :) Thanks.

Comment: Please be advised this community does not provide you copy-pastable codes at least in most cases. The goal is to give a concept or a gist of what will help you to solve the problem. Since I came so far on this one, why not to try another shot? This time I included the objective you wanted. @J_A_F_Casillas

Comment: Hello Soroush, I appreciate the time you take to help me out with this. I understand that the dynamics here are about teaching to fish instead of giving the fish, but I ask for clarification due to 2 things: I'm a Swift rookie and I already tried other methods that were not suitable for my case. I really thank you for your observations. Another question now: my `cellForRowAt` method is working no more when I implemented your struct case, how can I fix it? I tried with `ìndexpath.section/row`but it does not work. Thanks again for your support and patience.

Comment: No worries I'm not gonna leave you until you get your answer;) try `cell.textLabel!.text = dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].title`. your data source is simply a 2 dimensional array in which the first axis is the section and second is the row. Try not to merge your code with mine if it does not work. Create a new project and follow from step one. Maybe you're missing something that I cannot understand.

Comment: If you are still struggling with the problem, I pushed the solution to a repo on [github](https://github.com/faderani/Searching-Table-View) @J_A_F_Casillas

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, Soroush, it is really helpful. Your patience is highly appreciated. One more (and probably last) question: How can I use the filter in the searchBar to find any character included in the title? I tried to use something like `item.contains(searchText.lowercased())` but when I delete the text, my sections remain empty (does not reload the table view to its initial values). Thanks again for the help (now I look for a possible answer in other forums but if you can (again, please) help out with this, it would be great). Greetings.

Comment: When you delete the text, the delegate will be called and the table will be filtered based on an empty string. Therefore, no item will match that empty string. I pushed another commit which solves this problem. And if your problem is solved, remember to mark this as a correct answer to let others with the same problem, stay notified. @J_A_F_Casillas